# A variable is assigned with objects, how do I return the number of objects in the variable

Tags: variables, object

I have an object assigned to a variable `bio`. I just want to return the number of objects assigned to bio (in this case 1).

```
var bio = {
    "name" : "Dave Smith",
    "role" : "Web developer",
};
```

I can find the number of key value pairs but I just want the number of objects.
New at this so not sure if this makes sense.

Is it even possible to have multiple objects in a variable?

any help appreciated.

Comment: Which language is this? What do you mean by "number of objects" here? What do you consider the difference between a key/value pair and an object? What would multiple objects look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions here (I assume you use javascript):

1. How to know how many objects are assigned to a variable?

You need to do `.length` on the object. Note that this will work only on something that can be enumerated e.g. array.

```
var a = {foo: 'bar'};
a.length // undefined

var b = [{foo: 'bar'}];
b.length // 1
```

2. How to store multiple objects inside a variable

You need to use arrays like so: `var bio = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}];`